# configuring TCP/IP port filter in windows 2000 using CMD

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, ip, tcp

i am currently facing a problem to permit a certain TCP/IP Filtering port using CMD.

I have a windows 2000 and is unable to go to control panel. its like an empty windows. no control panel and other GUI. However I am able to run the CMD.

I want to permit TCP/IP port 5900. I searched online and the guides are filled with using GUI ( control panel -> network and sharing center -> change adapter setting -> .... )

is there a way to permit port 5900 using CMD ?

Comment: https://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/zoo5netsh